# Access is denied. ; Input/output error when trying to train a tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to run https://github.com/sentdex/pygta5
ver 0.01

and getting :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file H:\PYauto\pygta5\Versions\v0.01: Unknown: NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: H:\PYauto\pygta5\Versions\v0.01 : Access is denied.

; Input/output error
     [[{{node save_1/RestoreV2}}]]
```

............
https://pastebin.com/6NiGjgGp

TensorFlow CPU

python 3.6

CPU = intel i5-8500
how can I fix it, if possible without using ubuntu dual boot on my windows pc or using VMs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: run cmd as an administrator